# how to check the similarity between 2 regions in the same image , and how to show each region separately as input image?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

i have image with many region ,each region have unique number
 i need to compare each region with other regions if there is a similarity between them or no
Now the questions: 
1- Which the best method to find the similarity between separated regions ?
2- How i can show pixel coordinates as original image (input image)?
i am try to find this coordinates by using:

```
load Region;
image=imread('1.png')
[d1,d2] = find(Region == 1);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqCq0.png)

Comment: Regions are similar if they have the same kinds of animals living in them. As for "show pixel coordinates as original image", I have no idea what that means. In other words, your question needs a great deal of clarification before anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: To add on the first comment: are regions considered similar if they contain the same number? Are regions the considered similar if they have similar shape? How similar do they need to be until you call them similar? How do you quantify similarity?